# Country changes time zone behavior

Tags: dates

My country used to change from -3 to -2 first Sunday of October and then back in March.

Four or five months ago government announced the time will not change this year.

Yesterday was the first Sunday of October and here came the mess.
Almost no ntp servers were notified about that change and almost all clocks adjusted automatically from internet changed their time.

At this time, next day, I have good time in my iPhone 5s (iOS 9.02) and Ubuntu 12.04; bad time in my iPad mini 2 (iOS 8.4) and iMac OS 10.9. My Garmin Oregon 450 (GPS) gets the bad time.

A real mess.

I think it is absurd to change each hardaware settings like old times and set them manually.

I suppose it should be our government authority who had to anticipate this problem and act accordingly.

It seems they did not.  So my question is what can we, end users, do 'propagate' this time change, if posssible?

How is that kind of changes be notified to all ntp servers++ ?

I really don't know where is the best place to post these questions, I started here.  Maybe you can suggest other sites/forums

Edit: time.windows.com and other Windows time options also didn't update the info

Comment: I'm not sure how this is on-topic for Pro Webmasters? Are you experiencing this timezone inconsistency on your server for sites you manage?

Comment: I know it is highly probable that this matter does not belong here. I don't know where it could be posted. I didn't mention I manage a dedicated server located in a foreign country (Canada). There, the time is good.  What I've described is not my personal problem but a general issue in my country.  It seems many ntp or other time servers have not the correct information about the real time in my country. I want to know if is there something I can do to correct it. In my iMac I've just upgraded to El Capitan OS and the time is good now

Comment: Time changes can be frustrating. I am not sure why we all don't just pick one time zone with no changes for our operations. Take Google for example. Different systems work on different time zones- it could be midnight on one and 3am on another. Wouldn't it be better if they were at least all on California time? I worked for a major global telecom, several at different times, and time especially for billing was always a factor. We used one time zone for all switching systems and adjusted for local time in the billing data. Made life a lot easier!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about webmastering.

Comment: Questions on **professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Pro Webmasters. You may be able to get help on [sf]. As your question is currently written it *probably* would not meet that site's quality guidelines. I recommend reading their [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/about) to ensure your question is appropriate for their site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Almost no ntp servers were notified...

It's not the purpose of the NTP server to hold information about the time zones (and corresponding DST). The NTP server "simply" responds with an accurate UTC time.

It is generally up to the OS and server-software to hold information about the time zones. If a particular system is incorrect then it's that system that needs to be updated.

In the case of Windows this is something that is delivered periodically via Windows Updates.

If you are working with PHP then PHP has its own database. This can be manually updated by [downloading the latest from PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) (based on the [IANA Time Zone Database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones)) and recompiling PHP. The latest update, at the time of writing, being version 2015.7 (dated 2015-10-03 / 3 days ago).

> what can we, end users, do 'propagate' this time change

Unfortunately, I suspect "not a lot". Apart from logging a bug and hoping they'll push out an update sometime soon.

Comment: No problem in server with php.  It is a government fault to not to advice Windows, Garmin ++ servers the time zone won't change